# WYSYWIG HTML screen grid editor library for arranging components

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I'd like to build monitoring dashboards similar to what you can do with freeboard or emoncms. I'm looking for a (js) library that might help with letting users define the dashboard layout in drag & drop fashion.
Does soemthing like this exist as an embeddable library?

Answer (score 0):

I've just found jsplumbtoolkit (https://jsplumbtoolkit.com/demos/) which is exactly what I was looking for. A free community edition is available.